# How do I enable CTRL + Scroll zooming?

Tags: macos

My colleague just did <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Scroll</kbd> scrolling to zoom his screen and is telling me it's a default setting, but it doesn't work for me. Where do I enable that?

Comment: What version of OSX are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be under System Prefs>Trackpad (or mouse, if you use that instead)>Screen Zoom options:

[image: System Prefs>Trackpad]

[image: Screen zoom options]

Comment: I think in Lion it's different, you have to go to accessibility options.

Comment: Yep. On Lion, go to System Preferences > Universal Access. In the "Seeing" tab, click the "Options..." button that's in the Zoom section of the window. In the window that appears, select the checkbox at the bottom that says "Use scroll wheel with modifier keys to zoom".